# Selenium IDE in FireFox : login issue

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using Selenium's IDE in FireFox to do some testing, and I want Selenium to login yet i cant.

[website](https://cwciportal.cfm56.com)

Source

```
<td>click</td>
<td>css=input[type=&quot;SUBMIT&quot;]</td>
<td></td>
```

logs

> [error] Element css=input[type="SUBMIT"] not found

Comment: Looks like there isn't a valid input element of type submit. Your Selenese should work.  Can you show the snippet of Html? or possibly the page hasn't finished loading when you try to run the action?

Answer (score 0):

try to find this fields using Name:

```
document.getElementsByName('USERNAME')[0]
document.getElementsByName('PASSWORD')[0]
```

and find button using xpath:

```
"//input[text()='Sign in']"
```